# Is the DataTypeAttribute validation working in MVC2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, email, data-annotations

As far as I know the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataTypeAttribute not works in model validation in MVC v1. For example,

```
public class Model
{
  [DataType("EmailAddress")]
  public string Email {get; set;}
}
```

In the codes above, the Email property will not be validated in MVC v1. Is it working in MVC v2?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`[DataType("EmailAddress")]` doesn't influence validation by default. This is `IsValid` method of this attribute (from reflector):

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    return true;
}
```

This is example of custom DataTypeAttribute to validate Emails (taken from this site http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/08/12/CustomDataTypeAttributeValidationCustomDisplay.aspx):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple  = false)]
public class EmailAddressAttribute : DataTypeAttribute
{
    private readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public EmailAddressAttribute() : base(DataType.EmailAddress)
    {

    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {

        string str = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return true;

        Match match = regex.Match(str);   
        return ((match.Success && (match.Index == 0)) && (match.Length == str.Length));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want to make that regex static because setting the compiled option may cause compilation to be done everwhere the attribute is used and, if memory serves, generating a new in-memory assembly each time.

Comment: @Mike Scott: New in-memory assembly? What do you mean by that?

Comment: LukLed, what it says on the tin - an assembly created on the fly in memory ;-) Regex with the compiled option emits IL into an in-memory assembly. So to be sure you don't use up memory with each invocation, you should save the compiled regex instance and reuse it. see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2004/11/12/256783.aspx.

Comment: @Mike Scott: you're right, but if I'm not mistaken, an attribute is only instantiated once *per class*, not per object. This means that in practice the cost is pretty small. Nevertheless you're right that there's no cost in it being static. Should've been a const if the language would allow.

Comment: @skrebbel, so if you put the attribute on 10 classes, doesn't that mean 10 instantiations of the attribute and therefore 10 in-memory assemblies created for the same regex expression?

Comment: Sure thing! But not 10 in-memory assemblies per class *instance*. Still a significant difference. But yeah, good point :)

Comment: @skrebbel, absolutely! But then I did say everywhere the attribute is used - you mentioned instances, not me ;-) If you put the attribute without the regex declared static on 10 classes, you'll create 10 in-memory assemblies instead of 1. The real point here is that over-ambitious use of compiled regexes can use a lot of memory and even cause memory leaks. You have to be careful to declare them statically in most cases.

Comment: @LukLed -- The link is now broken.

Answer (score 13):

Like [LukLed pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391423/is-the-datatypeattribute-validation-working-in-mvc2/2391542#2391542), DataTypeAttribute doesn't do any validation by default. But it does influence templates regarding how the data is presented.

For example if you call `Html.DisplayFor()` method on a model that has `DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)` attribute, it'll format its value with `<a href="mailto:{0}">{0}</a>` (at least in MVC RC2).

Comment: Thanks for point out that DataTypeAttribute is not a validation attribute.

Comment: @Wayne: It actually is ValidationAttribute. It inherits from ValidationAttribute, but always returns true. You can override IsValid method and define your own, as it is in David Hayden's solution.

Comment: @LukLed, It indeed inherits from ValidationAttribute. I wonder why. Anyway, will correct that part.

Comment: `DataAnnotationsModelValidator` goes through every ValidationAttribute. DataTypeAttribute is ValidationAttribute, so it could be easily inherited and validation introduced. When you define your own data type, you can easily add validation.

Comment: @LukLed, Thanks. I edited the answer again to delete the part where it said it's not used for validation.

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, you can directly use RegularExpression attribute on your field instead of creating your own attribute that is in the end going to check for a regex matching.

```
[RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = PaErrorMessages.InvalidEmailAddress)]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from .NET 4.5 there is [EmailAddressAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), which has a correct implementation of the `IsValid` method. So if you're targeting .NET 4.5, then for validation please consider using the `EmailAddressAttribute` instead of a custom one. For example,

```
public class Model
{
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "INVALID EMAIL")]
    public string Email {get; set;}
}
```

And if you're curious about the implementation of `EmailAddressAttribute`, then here is the decompiled (using [JetBrains dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) decompiler) source of the class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Resources;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
{
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
  public sealed class EmailAddressAttribute : DataTypeAttribute
  {
    private static Regex _regex = new Regex("^((([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])+(\\.([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])+)*)|((\\x22)((((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(([\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x7f]|\\x21|[\\x23-\\x5b]|[\\x5d-\\x7e]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(\\\\([\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0d-\\x7f]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]))))*(((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(\\x22)))@((([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))\\.)+(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))\\.?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    static EmailAddressAttribute()
    {
    }

    public EmailAddressAttribute()
      : base(DataType.EmailAddress)
    {
      this.ErrorMessage = DataAnnotationsResources.EmailAddressAttribute_Invalid;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
      if (value == null)
        return true;
      string input = value as string;
      if (input != null)
        return EmailAddressAttribute._regex.Match(input).Length > 0;
      else
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out Scott Guthrie's blog post on MVC 2 validation. It is excellent.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx