# Custom DataTypeAttribute not triggering validation correctly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

Related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391423/is-the-datatypeattribute-validation-working-in-mvc2)

I have created my own DateValidationAttibute to make sure a string is in a valid date format (e.g., MM/DD/YYYY)

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DateValidationAttribute : DataTypeAttribute
{
    public DateValidationAttribute() : base(DataType.Date){}

    //MM/DD/YYYY, MM-DD-YYYY
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        //validation logic
    }
}
```

I am trying to test this attribute with this code

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var invalidObject = new TestValidation {DateField = "bah"};
        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(invalidObject, null, null);
        var validationResults = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ValidationResult>();

        bool result = Validator.TryValidateObject(invalidObject, validationContext, validationResults);

        Assert.IsFalse(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, validationResults.Count);
    }

    private class TestValidation
    {
        [DateValidation(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date!")]
        public string DateField { get; set; }
    }
```

Unfortunately this isn't working.  I put a breakpoint at the DateValidationAttribute constructor, and the IsValid method.  It definitely hits the constructor, but never hits the IsValid method.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The method TryValidateObject has an overload that can take a boolean validateAllProperties as a fourth parameter. If not specified, it defaults to false, which is when it only checks some attributes.

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var invalidObject = new TestValidation {DateField = "bah"};
    var validationContext = new ValidationContext(invalidObject, null, null);
    var validationResults = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ValidationResult>();

    //Validate all attributes
    bool result = Validator.TryValidateObject(invalidObject, validationContext, validationResults, true);

    Assert.IsFalse(result);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, validationResults.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried creating ValidationAttributes using the `DataTypeAttribute` class and I'm not sure if this is wrong but extending the `ValidationAttribute` class has always worked for me.

"DataTypeAttribute doesn't do any validation by default. But it does influence templates regarding how the data is presented." taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391423/is-the-datatypeattribute-validation-working-in-mvc2)

Example :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field,  AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class MyCustomAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
  public MyCustomAttribute()
    : base("Custom Error Message: {0}")
  {
  }

  public override bool IsValid(object value)
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: changing my example to extend from ValidationAttribute doesn't help.  Keep in mind that DataTypeAttribute already extends from ValidationAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772.aspx), note that only the required fields will be validated, **NOT** any other validation.

> This method evaluates each
>   ValidationAttribute instance that is
>   attached to the object type. It also
>   checks whether each property that is
>   marked with RequiredAttribute is
>   provided. **It does not recursively
>   validate the property values of the
>   object**.

You will want to change your test to this, note that we are setting the MemberName on the ValidationContext and telling the Validator to validate the invalidObject.DateField property.

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
     var invalidObject = new TestValidation { DateField = "bah" };
     var validationContext = new ValidationContext(invalidObject,null , null){MemberName = "DateField"};
     var validationResults = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ValidationResult>();

     var result = Validator.TryValidateProperty(invalidObject.DateField, validationContext, validationResults);

    Assert.IsFalse(result);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, validationResults.Count);
}
```

Comment: `only the required fields will be validated, NOT any other validation` Your statement is wrong, the quotation only claims that validatons are not performed recursive. That means, if you have a class with a complex type property that itself has properties marked with validation attributes, these **inner** properties are not validated.