# How can I validate an email address using the same method used by the DataAnnotations attribute DataType.EmailAddress?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC3 and in certain locations in the code I am using the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.EmailAddress` attribute and letting MVCs Model validation do the validation for me.

However, I would now like to validate an email address in a different section of code where I am not using a model. I would like to use the same method that is already being used by MVC, however I was unable to find any information on how to do so.

**EDIT** - Sorry if my question was unclear. I will attempt to clarify.

Here is a snippet from the RegisterModel that is included with the default MVC template:

```
    public class RegisterModel
    {
...

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [DisplayName("Email address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
...
     }
```

These attributes instruct mvcs model validation on how to validate this model.

However, I have a string that should contain an email address. I would like to validate the email address *the same way* that mvc is doing it.

```
string email = "noone@nowhere.com";
bool isValid = SomeMethodForValidatingTheEmailAddressTheSameWayMVCDoes(email);
```

Comment: if you provide some code to depict the scenario, it would be easier to answer

Comment: *I would now like to validate an email address in a different section of code where I am not using a model*. Could you show this section of your code so that we can have a base for discussion?

Comment: @BigJoe714, I updated my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Check this Example: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Email-model-validation-with-DataAnnotations-and-DataType-In-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said, the DataType attribute doesn't actually do any validation. I would recommend you to look at [Data Annotations Extensions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/) which includes already written validation extensions for a variety of things, including Email.

It is also possible to do model validation on your full model explicitly: [Manual Validation with Data Annotations](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx).

If you want to do per attribute validation for a specific field/property, you can also look at the [tests for DataAnnotationExtensions](https://github.com/srkirkland/DataAnnotationsExtensions/blob/master/DataAnnotationsExtensions.Tests/ValidationAttributes/EmailAttributeTests.cs) which should give you what you want:

```
[TestMethod]
public void IsValidTests()
{
    var attribute = new EmailAttribute();
    Assert.IsTrue(attribute.IsValid(null)); // Don't check for required
    Assert.IsTrue(attribute.IsValid("foo@bar.com"));
    ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this blog post by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx), which shows how to implement validation of an email address using a custom attribute (based on the RegularExpressionAttribute).

You can reuse that logic if you need to validate the email address somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this question: [Is the DataTypeAttribute validation working in MVC2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391423/is-the-datatypeattribute-validation-working-in-mvc2)

To summarize, `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` *doesn't actually validate anything*, it just says "hey, this property is supposed to be an e-mail address". Methods like `Html.DisplayFor()` will check for this and render it as `<a href="mailto:foo">foo</a>`, but the `IsValid()` method is pretty much a simple `return true;`.

You'll have to roll your own code to actually perform validation. The question linked above has some sample code you can use as a starting point.