# Is DataTypeAttribute is a validation attribute For DefaultModelBinder Class

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have just noticed that `DataTypeAttribute` class is inherited from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute`.

In terms of ASP.NET MVC `DefaultModelBinder` class, is `DataTypeAttribute` is a validation attribute? In plain English, does ModelBinder validate the object according to `DataTypeAttribute`?

For example, if I specify `DataType` property to `DataType.EmailAddress`, will it validate the e-mail address or this attribute is only providing metadata for objects.

**UPDATE**

I found a similar question on SO :

[Is the DataTypeAttribute validation working in MVC2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391423/is-the-datatypeattribute-validation-working-in-mvc2)

So, according to that it is not working as a validation attribute. So, why it is inherited from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute` if it is not serving as a validation attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataTypeAttribute does not contain any validation logic itself.

The reason it derives from ValidationAttribute is so that you could create a new custom data type class, which was both a DataType and a Validation, all wrapped up into one. It's an unfortunate side-effect of .NET not allowing multiple inheritance.

So, yes, it's a validator... that does no validation by default. It's waiting patiently for you to do the heavy lifting. :)

Actually, if you look inside of MVC 3 Futures, you'll see that we leveraged this to create new custom validators where we knew that jQuery was already capable of providing client-side validation logic, and we added mirrored server-side validation logic (and preserved the DataType benefits for templating).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the MVC3 source code the only purpose of the `DataTypeAttribute` is to populate the `ModelMetadata.DataTypeName` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.datatypename%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) .And this property is only used by the EditorFor/DisplayFor template generation. So you were right it has nothing to do with validation. So I don't know why is it inherited from `ValidationAttribute`. Maybe the framework authors reserved it for future use.

Comment: It makes sense for it to be used by templating engine. But as far as I know razor view engine is not generating Html5 elements by default. Did you dig into how they use it?

Comment: No for e.g.: `DataType.EmailAddress` it won't generate `<input type="email" />` it will be used only for the [Html.EditorFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402949.aspx) and [Html.DisplayFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407390.aspx) methods to pick up the default template. Which is for email is a mailto link in display mode and a textbox in edit mode.