# ASP.Net MVC not rendering email as type="email"

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

In my model I have:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
public string EmailAddress {get; set;}
```

However in my view (source) this renders as:

```
<label for="EmailAddress">EmailAddress</label>
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The EmailAddress field is required"
    id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" type="text" value="" />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="EmailAddress" data-valmsg-replace="true">
```

I thought this should have rendered with **type="email"** rather than type="text" - so when validating on the client side, it does not pickup if the email is not in a valid format.

**EDIT**

Further more, when I call **if (ModelState.IsValid)** it returns true, even if the email address is not in the correct format.  so even if the browser does not support HTML5, I would have thought that the IsValid in the controller would then have enforced the validation - is that not the case?

Is there something else I need on my model, to force type="email" so this correctly checks for a valid email address?

Thanks you,

Mark

Comment: When creating your project, did you select the option for HTML5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DataType attribute doesn't do any validation or render the email attribute on the input. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453574/mvc-datatypedatatype-emailaddress-no-validation) question describes how to add email validation using either a regular expression or the  [Data Annotations Extensions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org) library.

Also if you use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { type = "email" })` (if using the HTML5 doctype) that will render the email attribute which will cause validation for compatible browsers - see [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation).

It also has the added advantage that some (most modern) smartphones will show an email keyboard (with *@* symbol and *.com*) for easier typing. See [Default To The Numeric, Email, And URL Keyboards On The iPhone](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1721-Default-To-The-Numeric-Email-And-URL-Keyboards-On-The-iPhone.htm).

Answer (score 0):

This [input type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input) is only available in HTML5:

```
<input type="email" />
```

You can try to set doctype to HTML5 for your document like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**EDIT** But you won't be sure client browser will be able to treat / validate this input as an email.

Comment: Hi - thanks - it is set to HTML5, but obviously mt browser version is not ok with HTML5 - however, when posting back to the controller, I would have expected that would have picked up on the model not being valid?

Answer (score 0):

[This maybe just what you need](http://www.deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/asp-net-mvc-html5-toolkit/29). On that page it says that it supports the `Email` input type.

> There is also support for the following input types in the toolkit:
>   Text, Color, Email, Search, Time, Tel, File, Date, Datetime, Month,
>   Week, Range, Number