# Error message is not showing up as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "A Valid Email Address is Required.")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is Required.")]
public string email { get; set; }

<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email, "Email:")
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.email, new { @Style = "height:20px; width:300px; resize:none;", id = "emailV" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email)
</div>
```

I'm putting in a false email on purpose so the error message shows up on the page but it never does and if I leave it blank then the required error message shows up as expected. How can I get the valid email address error to show up on the page as well instead of just throwing an exception?

Comment: can you show the false email which you have written in form

Comment: I just wrote random letters just to see if the error would be thrown or not

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989081/email-model-validation-with-dataannotations-and-datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "A Valid Email Address is Required.")]
```

instead of

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "A Valid Email Address is Required.")]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this as mentioned by [polybios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2075015/polybios)

Model

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "A Valid Email Address is Required.")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is Required.")]
public string email { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

add below javascript in the page.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in the web.config file pls add/check below tags

```
 <appSettings>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

or 
[mvc [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress) no validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453574/mvc-datatypedatatype-emailaddress-no-validation)
pls try above two thing and pls let me know