# Datatype validation is not working in web form scaffolding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, webforms, scaffolding

I am using the Web Forms Scaffolding tool using visual studio for web forms.  Everything works great so far except the Datatype email and phone number validation does work as expected.  There is data validation checks when you add:

```
 [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber, ErrorMessage = "Phone number is not valid")]
 public string TitleEmail { get; set; }

 [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Email address is not valid")]
```

Without overriding the validation, I had to use a regular expression.

```
[RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Email was invalid.")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid phone number format.")]
```

Does anyone know why the default validation isn't working for Web Forms Scaffolding or get it to work again?

Comment: I think you need to add the `[EmailAddress]` attribute... see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453574/mvc-datatypedatatype-emailaddress-no-validation for possible duplicate

Comment: @DrewJordan adding [EmailAddress] and [Phone] seems to work for it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding as an answer...

You can use the `[EmailAddress]` attribute to validate an email address. in .NET 4.5. The `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` is only for display purposes (using `DisplayFor` will cause it to render a `mailto` link instead of plain text).